# This is the sum problem between the elements in the list. Why does "None" come out?

Tags: python, list, function

```
def add(t1, t2):
if len(t1) == len(t2):
    for i in range(len(t1)):
        [t1[i]+t2[i]]
elif len(t1) != len(t2):
    return None

t1 = [42, 1024, 23]
t2 = [6, 28, 496]
t3 = add(t1, t2)
print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

The problem of elements in the list is too difficult for me.
Please give me a little help.

Comment: You only return `None` from your function, why do you expect to see something else? Also `[t1[i]+t2[i]]` constructs a list then discards it, effectively doing nothing.

Comment: you don't return anything in case `len(t1) == len(t2)`

Comment: you could write `return [(t1[i] + t2[i]) for i in range(len(t1))]`, would not be very elegant though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of pairwise sums, you can modify your code as follows:

```
def add(t1, t2):
    if len(t1) == len(t2):
        result = []
        for i in range(len(t1)):
            result.append(t1[i]+t2[i])
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

Of course, there are utils that make this shorter:

```
def add(t1, t2):
    if len(t1) == len(t2):
        return [*map(sum, zip(t1, t2))]
    # None returned implicitly
```

This built-in-ladden code can be interpreted as *"map the sum function onto the pairs produced by zip and unpack the resulting sums into a list"*.

See some documentation:

- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [unpacking with `*`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#abstract)

Comment: using unpacking you could also provide `t1`..`tn` instead of two explicit arguments explicit

Comment: I know, but that changes the functionality of the function as well as its signature argument structure. The latter can be remedied by using `def add(*t)`.

Answer (score 0):

or be short:

```py
def add(t1, t2):
    return [sum(i) for i in zip(t1, t2)] if len(t1) == len(t2) else None
```

or even shorter:

```py
def add(*x):
    return [*map(sum, zip(*x))] if set(map(len, x)) == 1 else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by returning from if statement.

```
def add(t1, t2):
    if len(t1) == len(t2):
        return [(t1[i] + t2[i] ) for i in range(len(t1)) ]
    
    return None
```